# JavaFX wont import

Tags: java, javafx

Ok...

- I downloaded the .zip and unzipped it.
- I put the content in the subfolder /lib directly under my working map.
- I typed: *import javafx.application.Application;* in a file together with a simple hello world - and called the fil GUI.java
- I opened the terminal and navigated to the folder.
- I typed $ javac -cp lib GUI.java
- I typed $ javac -cp /lib GUI.java
- I typed $ javac -cp ./lib GUI.java

...and a dozen of other combinations to set the classpath to include the javafx -jars
All i get is:

> GUI.java:2: error: package javafx.application does not exist

What is wrong?

I'm using Java 11.0.5, Ubuntu and Emacs.

Comment: What zip did you download? What’s in your lib folder now?

Comment: Latest version from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ 
(openjfx-13.0.2_linux-x64_bin-sdk.zip)

In the lib-map there is a numboer of jar-files  named javafx.something.jar

Comment: What is the output of `ls lib`?

Comment: javafx.base.jar
javafx.controls.jar
javafx.fxml.jar
javafx.graphics.jar
javafx.media.jar
javafx.properties
javafx.swing.jar
javafx-swt.jar
javafx.web.jar
libavplugin-54.so
libavplugin-56.so
libavplugin-57.so
libavplugin-ffmpeg-56.so
libavplugin-ffmpeg-57.so
libavplugin-ffmpeg-58.so
libdecora_sse.so
libfxplugins.so
libglassgtk2.so
libglassgtk3.so
libglass.so
libgstreamer-lite.so
libjavafx_font_freetype.so
libjavafx_font_pango.so
libjavafx_font.so
libjavafx_iio.so
libjfxmedia.so
libjfxwebkit.so
libprism_common.so
libprism_es2.so
libprism_sw.so
output.txt
src.zip

Comment: Don't we have to add each JAR inside the folder ```lib``` to the classpath? ```javac -cp "javafx.base.jar:javafx.controls.jar:javafx.fxml.jar:<others>" <sources>```

Comment: Dont put such stuff into comments. Always update our question instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JFX SDK you downloaded contains `.jar` files. You need to put those jars (or at least the ones you need) on the classpath, not the directory containing them. So for example for `javafx.application.Application` you’d need `-classpath lib/javafx.graphics.jar`.

Alternatively, you could use Java's module system with something like

```
javac --module-path lib --add-modules javafx.graphics GUI.java
```

Comment: Thank you so much!